# Efficient way to "fill" a binary matrix to create smooth, connected zones

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, binary

I have a large matrix of 1's and 0's, and am looking for a way to "fill" up areas that are locally dense with 1's. 
I first did this task for an array, and counted the number of 1's within a certain radius of the element in questions. If the radius was 5, for example, and my threshold was 4, then a point that had 4 elements marked "1" within 5 elements to the left or right would be changed to a 1.

Basically I would like to generalized this to a two - dimensional array and have a resulting matrix that has "smooth" and "connected" regions of 1's and no "patchy" spots.

As an example, the matrix

1 0 0 1 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 1 0 0

0 1 0 1 0 0 0

0 0 1 1 1 0 0

would ideally be changed to

1 0 0 1 1 0 0

0 0 1 1 1 0 0

0 1 1 1 1 0 0

0 0 1 1 1 0 0

or something similar

Answer (score 1):

For binary images, the [morphologial operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology) that are [implemented in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) are perfect for manipulating the shape and size of connected regions.  Specifically, the process of [image closing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_%28morphology%29) is designed to fill holes in connected regions.  In MATLAB, the function is [`imclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html), which takes the image and a structuring element, similar to a filter kernel, for how neighboring pixels effect the filling of holes and gaps.  A simple invocation of `imclose` is,

```
IM2 = imclose(IM,strel(ones(3)));
```

Larger gaps can be filled by increasing the area of the influence of of neighboring pixes, via larger structuring elements.  For example, we an use a disk of radius 10 pixels:

```
IM2 = imclose(IM,strel('disk',10));
```

While, `imclose` supports grayscale and binary (0 and 1) images, the function [`bwmorph`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) is designed for operation on binary images only but provides a generic interface to all of the  morphological operations and various neat combinations of operations (e.g. `'bothat'`, `'tophat'`, etc.).  The syntax for closing is simplified with `bwmorph`:

```
BW2 = bwmorph(BW,'close');
```

Here the structuring element is the standard `ones(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple filter such as the following might do the trick:

```
h = [     0     1     0
          1     0     1
          0     1     0];

img2=(imfilter(img,h)>2) | img;
```

For instance:

```
img =

     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     0     0

img2 =

     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
```

You can try different filters to modify the output `img2`.

This uses the image processing toolbox. If you don't have that, you may want to look up equivalent routines from the matlab exchange.